# Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching namespace will it support with out appfabric server caching?

Tags: appfabric

Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching namespace will it support with out appfabric server caching?

Answer (score 1):

The question I *think* you're asking is: if I'm using the Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching namespace in my code, will it still work if I don't have AppFabric installed on the server?

AppFabric doesn't have to be installed on your web server, all the binaries necessary at runtime will be in your application's `bin` folder, but if it *isn't* installed, you'll need *at least* one other server that *does* have it installed. If you don't (or can't) have any servers with AppFabric installed then your application won't be able to use AppFabric caching and you'd be better to look at using `System.Runtime.Caching` instead.

Comment: whether System.Runtime.Caching is support in all Windows server?..if it is support..?..what is difference?..

Comment: @rengarajg System.Runtime.Caching is part of the .NET Framework 4.0 so it will run on Windows Server 2003 and 2008.

Comment: ok..Thanks..that is coding side ok..i have one doubt..I have developed .net application using appfabric caching serrver in windows 2008 server..because appfabric caching server only installed in IIS 7..my point of view..windows 2003 server will support?..what will i do if suppose windows 2003 server scenerio case?..how to implement this issue in older version server?..please give me suggestion?..

Comment: @rengarajg AppFabric can only be installed on Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.

Comment: where is dll for System.Runtime.Caching..is it inbuild one..or we need to download some where?.