# Appfabric issues

Tags: appfabric

I am using Micrsoft AppFabric caching Server in my web application and hosted using Windows 7 server.  I am using `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching` namespace in my web application.  If suppose I have not used appfabic server used in window 2003 server this situation.  This Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching namespace how will it support without appfabric server caching?...is there any option to support previous version server?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching namespace will it support with out appfabric server caching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627037/microsoft-applicationserver-caching-namespace-will-it-support-with-out-appfabric)

Answer (score 0):

Havn't trouble reading your question but i think it pertains to versions of Cache Clients?   If you have a 2003 client you need to install the 2003 client dlls see below:

[Windows 2003](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=D1CA30DF-0E84-4388-8636-2EF87380600C&displaylang=en&displaylang=en) 
[Windows Server 2008 and Up](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2&displaylang=en)

As for server support, you have to have Windows Server 2008 or above... sorry.

Comment: ok..Thanks.if i have developed in windows7 server but end user want to work in windows 2003 server..on that time.Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching will support for 2003 server?..

Comment: but windows 2003 server could not installed appfabric server because appfabric will only install in IIS 7..so that is my issue..
please give me suggestion..

Comment: but windows 2003 server could not installed appfabric server because appfabric will only install in IIS 7..so that is my issue.. please give me suggestion.. – rengarajg 0 secs ago edit but windows 2003 server could not installed appfabric server because appfabric will only install in IIS 7..so that is my issue.. please give me suggestion..

Comment: You have to use 2008 to host your cache.  Your clients (things that read and put stuff into the cache) can be Windows 2003 and up. You just have to install the right client versions.

Comment: For 2008 server, which client version of a appfabric.. we have to install?

Comment: In older version Windows Server AppFabric - Windows Server 2003 Distributed Cache Client case scemorio..how can we rectify issue with windows 7 server or new version?..what will i do for older version comes?..

Comment: See the above windows 2008 installer.  I dont understand the above... question what do you mean rectify issue?